# Passing bool values to function

Tags: python-2.7, boolean

I have the following script:

```
color = False
shape = False
light = False

print 'Starting conditions: \ncolor %s \nshape %s \nlight %s' % (color, shape, light)

c = raw_input("'c' to set color > ")
s = raw_input("'s' to set shape > ")
l = raw_input("'l' to set light > ")

args = []
args.append(c)
args.append(s)
args.append(l)

print "You selected: \ncolor %s \nshape %s \nlight %s" % (c, s, l)
raw_input()
print "Argument list: ", args
raw_input

for item in args:
    if 'c' in args:
        color = True
    elif 's' in args:
        shape = True
    elif 'l' in args:
        light = True

print "Now the final function..."
raw_input()


def funcs(color, shape, light):
    print "Color: %s \nShape: %s \nLight: %s" % (color, shape, light)

funcs(color, shape, light)
```

And my output is this:

```
[...]
>>> Now the final function...

>>> Color: True 
>>> Shape: False 
>>> Light: False
```

I can' seem to figure out why the other values aren't changed to `True`, probably my loop isn't right? I'm new to Python and programming in general so there is probably some basic thing I'm missing. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop

```
for item in args:
    if 'c' in args:
        color = True
    elif 's' in args:
        shape = True
    elif 'l' in args:
        light = True
```

It loops over the list `args` which has 3 items so it loops 3 times. First it checks if `'c'` is in `args` and if it is, it sets `color = True`, and it will never enter any of the `elif`s.

Now because you loop over `args`, and then check `if 'c' in args:` on each iteration, it enters this `if` on each iteration because every time, `'c'` is still in `args`.

What you probably meant to do:

```
for item in args:
    if 'c' in item:
        color = True
    elif 's' in item:
        shape = True
    elif 'l' in item:
        light = True
```

(Changed the `in args:` to `in item:` )

This will check the current `item`, i.e. each iteration checks a different entry in the `args` list instead of the entire list each time.

Comment: Oh yes! I knew it was something like that... Sometimes I focus on the details instead of looking at the overall thing.